# How to resolve $ is undefined inside jQuery plugin file?

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem of `$` and jQuery. I am using jQuery vector map and JavaScript generating error:

> $ is undefined in jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js

and plugin file path. If I tried with `$ = jQuery` it made disable other JavaScript. I went into plugin file that has zipped code, and placed `$ = jQuery` but it made disable other jQuery code, following is some string of code of file.

```
$ = jQuery;
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap',
```

and much more code to draw map. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: ARe you definitely loading jQuery before this other script?

Comment: yes, i am using inside wordpress, and if i remove these files, other jquery plugins work fine.

Comment: sorry, that is $ is undefined

Answer (score 1):

wrap the plugin in this:

`(function($){/*plugin code*/})(jQuery)`

Answer (score 0):

$ is undefined is usually because jquery library hasn't been included.  You have a jquery plugin - jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js but this will be dependent on jquery.[some-version].js being included before it.

Check the documentation for the plugin and it will list what dependencies are needed.